# Visual Studio Code set to use PS7, but runs as PS5

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I have Visual Studio Code set to use PowerShell 7.1 for the session. If I click on the PowerShell icon in the bottom right corner (to show the PowerShell session menu), the drop down bar at the top confirms it is PowerShell 7.1.

But when I click the Run button to run the script, it runs using PowerShell 5. Normally that isn't a problem for me, but I'm currently doing something that requires a PS7 feature so have set the #requires parameter.

The command that is executed is `powershell -executionpolicy ByPass -File <my file>.ps1`. My guess is there is a parameter somewhere to allow me to change that to `pwsh` but I cannot find it.

I've been working around this for a few weeks by just having Windows Terminal open to run the script over there when I need to. Today I got so frustrated by this and spent about a solid hour trying to find out where the setting is but I haven't been able to find anything.

Does anyone have any idea what the setting I need to change may be?

Comment: you must use `pwsh.exe` instead of `powershell.exe`. [*grin*]

Comment: I agree. Do you know where that is set so that when I click the Run button it goes to pwsh.exe?

Comment: You can set whatever default shell you choose in VSCode. So, not just a PowerShell thing. The out of box default is Windows PowerShell, which can be changed via the VSCode user settings. Click the `Cog` in that bottom left corner, and select `Settings`., and make your changes. If you want to get more granular, you can open the `Settings.json` file to make changes. See the VSCode product guide for details.

Comment: when i installed ps7+ it asked for permission to set ps7+ as the default VSCode shell. also, as postanote mentioned ... you can go into the settings for VSCode and set it there

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer - it was an extension. I hadn't released that my default run button (and key combination) wasn't the standard one but the one provided by the Code Runner extension. Once I disabled the extension and everything was as it should be. I don't even remember installing that extension so I'll leave it disabled until I remember why I needed it (or until I get some free time to dig into the extension's settings). Thanks